# AWS S3 versioning update latest version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to write an new object to s3 bucket that has versioning enabled for a key that already exists and I want this new object to replace the latest version of that key. How can I use put in my new object to overwrite the existing version? I don't need the latest version any more it contains a mistake and I'm ok with permanently deleting it.

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
resource = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = resource.Object(bucket, output_key)
latest_version = obj.version_id
obj.put(Body=body, version=latest_version) # I don't want to create a new version as it would with obj.put(Body=body)
```

Comment: You don't put to a version, you put it to a key just like non versioned buckets. It then becomes the latest version automatically. And ***obviously*** you cannot overwrite versions, what would be the point of versions if you could!?

Comment: I take it you never made a mistake before @luk2302

Comment: Whaaat? What does that have to do with anything??

Comment: obviously the version I'm trying to overwrite contains a mistake, it doesn't need to exist

Comment: Then the question is not about overwriting a version but actually deleting a version!? Those are VERY different things. What is your actual goal and why? Delete for now but recoverable, permanently delete, ...? Why actually delete at all? Does it contain information that needs to be permanently gone??

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to just delete the latest version then write your object, however this does not preserve the version_id:

e.g.

```
    obj = resource.Object(bucket, output_key)
    obj.delete(VersionId=obj.version_id)
    obj.put(Body=body)
```